# Find feature by property from multiple layers

Tags: openlayers

What is the best way to find a particular feature by a property (let's say id), where the feature could exist in one of many layers? I could theoretically step through all the layers, and step through all the features in those layers until I find it, but I was hoping there would be a better/faster way.

Basically, here is the way I'm doing it, but would rather a better way if one exists:

```
map.getLayers().forEach(function (lyr) {
  const layerSource = lyr.getSource();
  const features = layerSource.getFeatures();
    for (const feature of features) {
        if (feature.get("id")=== valueIAmLookingFor){
            //do something
        }
    }
});
```